# How to rerender part of html tree in angular?

Tags: angular

I have the issue with next code

```
<form (ngSubmit)="formService.save(form)" #form="ngForm">
    <input [disabled]="true" />
    <input />
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>

class FormService {
    async save(form: NgForm): Promise<void> {
        form.form.disable(); // all the form has been disabled
        await httpClient.post(...);
        form.form.enable(); // all the form has been enabled, but I need to keep input disabled, as `true` passed in the html template
    }
}
```

is it possible to do smth like this: `form.detectChanges()` to update controls state from the attributes, to keep controls disabled marked in html as disabled after `form.enable()`?

see that stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-szm5v6?file=src/app/app.component.html

PS. I have tried to catch the disable value from the html, however it is not working for custom form-controls, e.g. mat-checkbox from angular material:

```
<mat-form-field [disabled]="true"></mat-form-field>
```

on the prod build there will be nothing on the mat-form-field, so it will be impossible to restore the state from the html

however I hope it possible to tell control to update state from html tree

Comment: You should not use `[disabled]` directly in the HTML. You should call `formControl.disable()` on this field instead

Comment: Also, I try to reproduce on a StackBlitz but it seems that `NgForm::enable/disable` do not exist. I suppose that you modified the code before posting it but maybe there is a mistake somewhere in the typing

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle wish to use the `[disabled]` as it is more intuitive with template-driven forms that are used, however there is requirement to disable the whole form while performing async operations.. I have updated the question with working stackbliztz.